# Anonymous type parameter with type constraint

Tags: c#, generics, anonymous-types, type-constraints

I need to call some methods on an object, but I am not able to know its type parameter. I essentially need something like this:

```cs
abstract class SomeClass<T> where T : SomeClass<T> {
    public abstract void SomeMethod();
}

class SomeSubClass : SomeClass<SomeSubClass> {
    public override void SomeMethod() { ... }
}
```

```cs
SomeClass<object> obj = SomeGenericFunction<SomeClass<object>>();
obj.SomeMethod();
```

But this wouldn't work currently, because `T` has a type constraint.

##### EDIT:

`SomeClass` and `SomeSubClass` are provided by a library, so they are set.

Comment: Can you give a more realistic example of what you're trying to accomplish? What's the point of `T : SomeClass<T>`, you're essentially making T the containing class.

Comment: please read this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/where-generic-type-constraint before

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are making your T recursive

```
abstract class SomeClass<T> 
   where T : SomeClass<T> // You can't use SomeClass again here
{
    public abstract void SomeMethod();
}
```

If you want invoke a method in different kind of objects, define an interface:

```
public interface IYourInterface
{
    void SomeMethod();
}
```

Implement it in several classes:

```
public class My1 : IYourInterface
{
    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        // Your code
    }
}

public class My2 : IYourInterface
{
    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        // Your code
    }
}
```

Create objects of any type and invoke it:

```
var list = new List<IYourInterface>
{
    new My1(),
    new My1(),
    new My2()
};

foreach (var item in list)
{
    item.SomeMethod();
}
```

If you want a container of objects, you need do something like that:

```
public abstract class SomeClass<T> 
    where T : IYourInterface
{
    public abstract void Run();
}

public class SomeSubClass : SomeClass<IYourInterface>
{
    public override void Run()
    {
        // Invoke SomeMethod of your items
    }
}

var instance = new SomeSubClass();

// I suppose you add IYourInterface instances to SomeSubClass and 
// use Run to iterate it
// instance.Add(new My1());
// instance.Add(new My2());
// In that case, you must create an Add method in SomeClass

instance.Run();
```

Comment: I really like that solution, but i should have mentioned, that these classes are not my own. They are provided by a library, that I cannot change! So sadly no Solution for me! :(

Comment: And the classes are "where T : SomeClass<T>", with the infinite recursion? It doesn't make much sense

Comment: It is used in the common microsoft class builder style, where you contruct classes by using a sepered builder class, where you can chain so called "with methods". Builders with common features are abtracted with these recursive super classes...